# Classify number of solutions of $x^n \equiv a \mod 2^{\alpha}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Consider the equation $x^n \equiv a \mod 2^{\alpha}$ with  $ x \in \mathbb{Z_{2^\alpha}}$, $a$ is even and $\alpha \geq 1$.

I tried to consider $a=2^ka_1$ with $a_1$ an odd integer to classify the number of solutions. 
If $a^{2^{\alpha}/\gcd(n,\phi(2^\alpha))} \equiv 1 \mod 2^\alpha (*) $   then the number of solutions is $\gcd(n,\phi(2^\alpha))$.
But i'm not really sure if (*) is true for such $a$.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Since $a$ is even and $a^{2^{\alpha}/\gcd(n,\phi(2^\alpha))}$ is even and cannot have a remainder $1 \bmod {2^{\alpha}}.$

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is even then so is $x^n$. This can only be true if $x$ is even, but then $x^n = 0 \mod 2^n$. So we must have $a = 0$ and every even $x$ is a solution.